# How to tell if a phone's background will rotate

Tags: android, orientation

I know a lot of a Android phones do *not* rotate the background on the main screen, but some do. Is there a way to tell if the phone/device that's running will rotate the main screen/background?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it isn't so much whether it will or will not rotate, but under what circumstances it will. My phone's orientation will not cause the home screen to go landscape, but opening the physical keyboard will. Just my 2 cents, it might not be that clear cut